# ASP C# Time code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I'm trying to make a stopwatch.
I've used a code from the internet to count the minutes and seconds:
This is the code( works fine)

```
    public partial class Ingelogd2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
            }
}



private static Stopwatch sw;
    protected void tm1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long sec = sw.Elapsed.Seconds;
        long min = sw.Elapsed.Minutes;

    if (min < 60)
        {
            if (min < 10)
               Henkie.Text = "0" + min;
            else
                Henkie.Text = min.ToString();

                Henkie.Text += " : ";

            if (sec < 10)
                Henkie.Text += "0" + sec;
            else
                Henkie.Text += sec.ToString();
        }
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Response.Redirect("Ingelogd2.aspx");
        }
    }
} 
}
```

The result I'm getting from this code is for example: 00:14  ( after 14 seconds displayed on the label "Henkie")

Now I've tried to add hours aswell, so I've made this code:

```
    public partial class Ingelogd2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
            }
}


    private static Stopwatch sw;
    protected void tm1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long sec = sw.Elapsed.Seconds;
        long min = sw.Elapsed.Minutes;
        long hour = sw.Elapsed.Hours;
        long day = sw.Elapsed.Days;

        if (day < 1)
        {
            if (hour < 10)
                Henkie.Text = "0" + hour;
            else 
                Henkie.Text = hour.ToString();

                Henkie.Text += " : ";
            if (min < 10)
               Henkie.Text = "0" + min;
            else
                Henkie.Text = min.ToString();

                Henkie.Text += " : ";

            if (sec < 10)
                Henkie.Text += "0" + sec;
            else
                Henkie.Text += sec.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Response.Redirect("Ingelogd2.aspx");
        }
    }
} 
}
```

I wanted so it would display for example (00:12:16 after 0 hours, 12 minutes, 16 seconds) but I't doesnt work. It only displays 12:16 after 0 hours, 12 minutes, 16 seconds. I have no idea why this doesn't work. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: you missed += in two places change  Henkie.Text = min.ToString(); to  Henkie.Text += min.ToString(); also Henkie.Text = "0" + min; to Henkie.Text += "0" + min;

Comment: Or you could use the built in stopwatch object in the .Net Framework.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to change: Henkie.Text = "0" + min; to Henkie.Text += "0" + min;

Comment: try `Henkie.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hour, min, sec);`

Comment: I can't help but ask why you have `private static Stopwatch sw;`. Static means there is ONE instance of the stopwatch in the application and ALL users will refer to the same instance. So if two users are accessing the page at the same time, weird things will happen with the observed times...

Answer (score 3):

I have one question for you, which I'd love you to answer before you go on and read the actual solution.

Why are you doing all that? All that code I mean. All that manipulations, adding zeroes, all those if-else statements.

The real question is why complicate something simple?

Now your answer. Just display the `Elapsed` property. This will internally call the `ToString` with the `c` format, which will display `hh:mm:ss` with optional days if present.

And if you want to omit, let's say, the hours in the first example you still don't need to write all that code, you just:

```
sw.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss")
```